# How can I make a new slide show template?

Tags: slideshows, templates

Mathematica comes with some built-in slide show templates. If you select File / New / Slide Show, the choices pop up. How can I make my own template?

Comment: Without additional information about the context of your need for a new slide show template, all I can say is: derive a new style sheet from one of the existing slide show style sheets.

Comment: How would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started.

1. Start by opening a new slide show notebook by picking a template from  File > New > Slide Show ...
2. Open the [Style a
   nd Format Notebooks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/StyleAndFormatNotebooks.html) How-to page in the Documentation Center.

   The pertinent links on this page are [Create a New Style in a Stylesheet](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateANewStyleInAStylesheet.html) and [Install a Stylesheet](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/InstallAStylesheet.html)

Note that as well as creating a new style in a stylesheet you can also edit the already defined styles.